# Updating an axis when reordering bar charts in D3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've built a horizontal bar chart where the bars resort based on a a set of different criteria (stored as an array). While I can get the bars to sort what I can't seemed to do is get the y-axis to redraw or re-sort in line with the bars of the chart.

Here's the page now:
[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dte5X/2/)

Below is the code for writing the labels and sorting the bars:

```
var yAxisLabelNames = d3.scale.ordinal()
                        .domain(dataset.map(function(d){
                            return d.name;}))
                        .rangeRoundBands([padding, h - padding], 0.05);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                     .scale(yAxisLabelNames)
                     .orient("left");

svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
            .call(yAxis);
```

and one of my sorting functions:

```
d3.select("#patchCompetition")
            .on("click", function(){
                svg.selectAll("rect.bars")
                    .sort(function(a, b){
                        return d3.ascending(a.values[4], b.values[4])
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){
                        return i *50;
                    })
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                        return yScale(i)
                    });

                svg.selectAll(".labels")
                    .sort(function(a, b){
                        return d3.ascending(a.values[4], b.values[4])
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .delay(function(d, i){
                        return i * 50;
                    })
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
                        return yScale(i) +yScale.rangeBand() /2 +4;
                });

                svg.select(".y axis").call(yAxis);

            });
```

Comment: It looks like all the different options have the same y domain, so that redrawing the axis would effect no noticeable change. Is that the case?

Comment: Right now yes - what I'm trying to do is get the reordered domain from my sorting function `.sort(function(a, b){
                        return d3.ascending(a.values[4], b.values[4])
                    })`  I want to have the axis domain change to mirror this (basically the domain has changed and I need the axis to reflect this)

Comment: I may be missing something -- wouldn't you just update the domain and then redraw the axis?

Answer (score 0):

Using `selection.sort` to reposition nodes is probably not the best way to go.  It is usually better to start with the data and let the DOM representation flow from that.  Think of the data as the anchor for all other representations and it will be easier to manage subsequent state changes in the chart.  For example, you  shouldn't need special handling like you have with your index-based `yScale`.

Each of your click handlers could:

1. Sort the dataset array.
2. Create (or modify) `yScale` setting domain to names in the same order as the data.
3. Set `yScale` into `yAxis` and render it.
4. Bind dataset to the bars and set `x` and `y` attribute by scaling as you're already doing.

If you want the bars to float around as they do now you can pass a key function to the `selection.data` call.  If you don't specify a key (default key of index) the bars will stay in place and just grow or shrink as they change what name they represent.

With this approach changes to the dataset will drive changes to the different representations in the document.